# Interactive rebase without editor

Tags: git, git-rebase

I want to split an unpushed commit in the near history of the current branch. As long as I know this only is possible using interactive rebase (or by doing it completely manually).

How to invoke the interactive rebase so it will not show an text editor, e.g. by preparing the result of the editing?

Comment: What would you like, or expect, to happen if you don't specify in the editor what you'll be rebasing?

Comment: I would expect an error. Just want to avoid Git launching the editor.

Comment: How about a terminal editor like nano or vim?

Comment: No, the command should be invoked by an application without user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand correctly that you want to do the following:

1. Prepare in advance (somewhere) your rebase interactive file
2. Do the rebase without ever opening a text editor (say, on a different machine)

You can do this as follows:

First create a fake text editor: add the following contents to an sh file called edit.sh

```
cat file > $1
```

where file refers to some location where you will put the instructions for the interactive rebase.

Make sure edit.sh is executable

Next, run the rebase as follows:

```
GIT_EDITOR=edit.sh git rebase -i branch_to_rebase_on
```

Instead of opening an editor; this will open the sh script. The sh script simply writes the instructions for the rebase to the rebase file.

Comment: Thanks. Is there another, platform independent way of doing this, e.g. by launching `git rebase -i` with a certain option?